# VSTS build failure with "Failed: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT 66.85.49.22:443"

Tags: protractor, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, saucelabs

We have protractor based e2e test suite in VSTS and a build have been configured to run the e2e test suite in saucelabs for every commit in the development repos. We are getting `"Failed: ETIMEDOUT connect ETIMEDOUT 66.85.49.22:443"` error during the test run and we are not sure what is causing this failure.

We checked the same with saucelabs team and the response was that the fix is with the VSTS build. It will be great if we could find a solution for the same.

We are not seeing the failure consistently. So we wanted to know were the fix need to provided.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be that the build time out is reached? Are the succesfull e2e builds taking shorter?

Comment: @WouterdeKort Thanks for sharing your point but if that is the case the build should fail consistently. Here the build fails inconsistently.

Comment: that's why I asked if the succeeding builds take less time. Maybe all your builds wobble around the time out and some succeed, others fail.

Comment: @WouterdeKort To explain in brief, For example, If we have 10 test cases in the build which runs in the saucelab once the build is triggered. Here out of 10, some fail with the issue reported. The same failed test gets passed for the next build run.

Comment: Does it run the 10 tests in the same order one every run?

Comment: This error usually happens when the tests can't connect to the selenium server for some reason. I would look for any issues connecting to saucelabs from VSTS. If you manually run the tests against saucelabs do you see this error?

Comment: Check the error comes from `webdriver-manager update` or `webdriver-manager start`.

Comment: @tehbeardedone We are getting error only when we connect saucelab from vsts

Comment: @WouterdeKort All the tests are executed in same order for every run but the error is occuring in random tests.